# What permissions to I need to use User Defined Table Types

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Background:

I have two accounts for the same database one "master" account and another (sub) account which I use for my website to use to connect to the server so I can manage what the user can and cannot do. A lot of the permissions on this account were already on there before I got access to it so I don't know what exactly all the permissions are, except the ones I have managed.

There is a user defined table type that some one else created, dont ask me why they did,

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[AffectedServiceList] AS TABLE(
    [AffSerName] [nvarchar](200) NULL
)
GO
```

This type is used in a stored procedure like so

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Contractsetup]  @OtherParams, --Easier than typing them all
                                       @list        dbo.AFFECTEDSERVICELIST READONLY
```

The master account can execute and modify this procedure perfectly but the sub account cannot run or modify this stored procedure while the affectedservicelist type is used as it gets the error

> Cannot find the type 'AffectedServiceList', because it does not exist
>   or you do not have permission.

I have tried doing this `grant execute on type::dbo.AFFECTEDSERVICELIST to subaccount`

But it still returns the same error that about the permissions. I have eliminated it to the the permissions as when I try and modify on the master account I just get

> Command(s) completed successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing a bit more digging the permission I needed to add was not `execute` it was `control`.

So instead of doing this;

```
grant execute on type::dbo.AFFECTEDSERVICELIST to subaccount
```

I actually needed to do this;

```
grant control on type::dbo.AFFECTEDSERVICELIST to subaccount
```

Comment: That is wrong: EXECUTE permission is sufficient to create a proc using user defined table type

Comment: Excuse me, you need REFERENCES permission too

Answer (score 10):

To use User Defined Table Type you need `EXECUTE` or `CONTROL` permission on it.
Your code

```
grant execute on type::dbo.AFFECTEDSERVICELIST to subaccount
```

is correct.

What is missing here is `REFERENCES` permission:

```
grant references on type::dbo.AFFECTEDSERVICELIST to subaccount
```

this is need to be able to reference this type in the code.

To only be able o create a proc using UDT, you only need `REFERENCES` permission. `EXECUTE` or `CONTROL` is needed to be able to execute the code(proc)

Comment: creating the procedure was fine as i created on master account, just needed the permission to execute it on subaccount